# ios - generating a PDF populated from CoreData

Tags: ios, pdf, core-data, printing

I have an app with Core Data and I would like to transfer its contents to a PDF file so the end user can print it and mail it.

1. What steps do I need to take? Like do I need to convert or can it be converted directly?
2. I would like to set the layout of the PDF file so I am not sure if that affects question 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outputting to PDF isn't particularly tricky - in general it's no harder than composing a traditional view.

UIKit provides a high-level API, documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW3).

An alternate approach is to render to a CoreGraphics PDF context. You can also search for various implementations of this.

Comment: Thanks:-) I'll check them out

Comment: Just letting you know - this is exactly what I needed:-)